# Align input in a div container

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I need to align input in a div. If the div clicked then the input should be shown otherwise a span should be shown.

My code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .cell-wrapper {
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .cell-wrapper,
      .cell-wrapper input {
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 15px;
      }

      .cell-wrapper span {
        padding: 0 6px;
      }

      .cell-wrapper input {
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
        <div>
            <table-cell v-for="col in cols" :key="col"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <script>
      const TableCell = {
        template: /*html*/ `
        <div @click="editing = true" class="cell-wrapper">
            <input
                v-if="editing"
                v-model="val"
                class="col"
                @blur="editing = false"
                @vue:mounted="({ el }) => el.focus()"
            />
            <span v-else>{{ val }}</span>
        </div>
        `,
        setup() {
          const editing = Vue.ref(false)
          const val = Vue.ref('')
          return {
            val,
            editing
          }
        }
      };
      const app = Vue.createApp({
        setup() {
          const cols = Vue.ref(5)
          return {
            cols,
          }
        }
      })
      app.component('table-cell', TableCell)
      app.mount('#root')
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code produce:

[image: first render of the page]

And when I change the input value, rendered page become (the expected value: all table-cell should be aligned in horizontally):

[image: unexpected rendered page]

I know that the problem is CSS proble but I don't understand the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can vertically align the elements by setting the parent div to `display: flex`

```
#root > div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .cell-wrapper {
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .cell-wrapper,
      .cell-wrapper input {
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 15px;
      }

      .cell-wrapper span {
        padding: 0 6px;
      }
      
      #root > div {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .cell-wrapper input {
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
        <div>
            <table-cell v-for="col in cols" :key="col"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <script>
      const TableCell = {
        template: /*html*/ `
        <div @click="editing = true" class="cell-wrapper">
            <input
                v-if="editing"
                v-model="val"
                class="col"
                @blur="editing = false"
                @vue:mounted="({ el }) => el.focus()"
            />
            <span v-else>{{ val }}</span>
        </div>
        `,
        setup() {
          const editing = Vue.ref(false)
          const val = Vue.ref('')
          return {
            val,
            editing
          }
        }
      };
      const app = Vue.createApp({
        setup() {
          const cols = Vue.ref(5)
          return {
            cols,
          }
        }
      })
      app.component('table-cell', TableCell)
      app.mount('#root')
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems good but the problem persist when focusing the input.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: It's work but the <table-cell /> component become  dependent to its container. It's not possible to do for table-cell elements?

Answer (score 0):

Try below CSS code i hope solve your issue:

```
.cell-wrapper {
      align-items: center;
      width: 100px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .cell-wrapper,
    .cell-wrapper input {
      height: 50px;
      font-size: 15px;
      display: flex;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .cell-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }

    .cell-wrapper span {
      padding: 0 6px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .cell-wrapper input {
      width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```